# What is this futuristic font?

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Can you help me find a font this cool?

Comment: Minor nit-pick: I'd label this 'retro-futuristic' as it's heavily based on 60s/70s era idea of 'future'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's **Amelia** (albeit a little stretched).

http://www.ascenderfonts.com/font/amelia.aspx

[image: Ascenderfonts Amelia]

Edit: found a similar variant, called **Permanence**:

http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/typodermic/permanence/

[image: MyFonts Permanence]